# How display multiple values in QLabel in Qcreator

Tags: qt, qlabel

I am developing calculator using Qt SDK I want to get values from the calculator buttons in to one Qlabel. I have designed GUI using design view I tried to get values using following code.

```
void MainWindow::on_three_button_clicked(){
    ui->label->setText("3");
}
```

but then Only I can get one button value at a time

please help me on this...

Comment: do you want to get values from clicked button ? please clear out your question

Comment: yes assume that I want to input 256 so I have to press 2 and 5 and 6 But in my program I can only enter 2 if I enter 5 after 2 its displaying as 5 not as 25 

I want to get 2 and 5 and 6 button values as 256

Answer (score 0):

You can have one `QString` variable to store current pressed value. Here I am considering your class variable defined as `QString myEnteredNum`. Then you can use it as below code:

```
void MainWindow::on_three_button_clicked(){
    myEnteredNum.append("3");          // This method you can add in each number slot
    ui->label->setText(myEnteredNum);
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general approaches to this. You can append the digits directly to a number, and bind the label to the number. The `m_first` label below is updated that way. You can also append the digits directly to the label. The `m_second` label is updated so.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Window : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(double number MEMBER m_number WRITE setNumber NOTIFY numberChanged)
  double m_number;
  QGridLayout m_grid;
  QLabel m_first, m_second;
  QPushButton m_digits[10], m_clear;
public:
  Window(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent),
    m_grid(this), m_clear("C") {
    m_grid.addWidget(&m_first, 0, 0, 1, 3);
    m_grid.addWidget(&m_second, 1, 0, 1, 3);
    m_grid.addWidget(&m_clear, 5, 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
      m_digits[i].setText(QString::number(i));
      if (i > 0) m_grid.addWidget(m_digits + i, 2 + (i-1)/3, (i-1)%3);
      else m_grid.addWidget(m_digits + i, 5, 1);
      QObject::connect(m_digits + i, &QPushButton::clicked, [i, this]{
        // Add the digit to the number
        setNumber(m_number * 10.0 + i);
        // Add the digit to the label
        m_second.setText(m_second.text().append(QString::number(i)));
      });
    }
    QObject::connect(&m_clear, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{
      setNumber(0);
      m_second.setText("0");
    });
    QObject::connect(this, &Window::numberChanged,
                     &m_second, &QLabel::setNum);
    emit m_clear.clicked(); // initialize everything
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void numberChanged(double);
  void setNumber(double n) { m_number = n; emit numberChanged(n); }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Window window;
  window.show();
  return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Finally, a calculator is stateful and, to avoid common mistakes, you could use a `QStateMachine` to make this fact explicit, and to adjust the behavior of the calculator depending on which state it's in.